# Phonegap android - deviceready event not fired

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, cross-platform

I had searched the web for solutions to my problem and found many related threads, unfortunately, none of the solutions provided works for my case. I am new to android development and followed the documentation found at [Apache Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)! for configuration.

**Problem**: The deviceready event is not fired, below are my codes and configuration together with error log. Please advise me on what i had done wrong, thanks!!!

**Emulator**

```
AVD Device: nexus 7
Target: Android 4.2
Memory RAM: 512
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.pollo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import org.apache.cordova.*;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }
    }
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script>
                function onLoad(){
                   console.log("Now Loading");
                   document.addEventListener("deviceready", myDeviceReadyListener, false);  
                }


                function myDeviceReadyListener(){
                    console.log("Device ready");
                    navigator.notification.alert("Phone is ready!");

                    var myDiv = document.getElementById('props');
                    myDiv.innerHTML = 'Device Name: ' + device.name;
                }
            </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="onLoad()">
        <h1>X App V.11</h1>
        <p id="props">Loading device properties...</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.pollo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="7"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            />    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:name="com.example.pollo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

    </manifest>
```

**Config**

```
assets>www>cordova-2.2.0.js
assets>www>index.html
res>xml>config.xml
AndroidManifest.xml
libs>cordova-2.2.0.jar
libs>android-support-v13.jar
```

**Logcat - Error Log**

```
 12-31 01:50:58.323: E/Trace(659): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 12-31 01:51:45.653: E/StrictMode(552): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1b278 that was originally bound here
```

The onLoad() is called but the myDeviceReadyListener() is not called~ Does it got anything to do with the emulator that i chose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Funny, just faced the same problem yesterday. I spent hours debugging and all I could find is that at line 6016 in cordova-2.2.0.js, the app seems to silently quit executing. Why? No idea... there are no errors in the logs. Perhaps some new permissions or something along those lines.

Anyway, after wasting many hours debugging, I started from scratch using the PhoneGap tutorial. I noticed that at the time when PhoneGap 2.2.0 was released, they had used API level 16, not 17 (which is what I was using and what you are using). As soon as I set the app's target to API Level 16 everything started working again.

Takeaway: set your app's target API level to 16 (Android 4.1.2) for now and your app will receive the deviceready event.

Comment: Cordova 2.2.0 was out before API level 17. Level 17 introduced a change which broke Cordova communication between the Java and JavaScript layers. If you build using API level 16 you'll be okay. The bug in question is fixed in 2.3.0 and you'll be able to build with API level 17 then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! As i m developing in a closed network, hence it took quite awhile for me to source for Android 4.1.2 and spent quite awhile to get it load with the AVD, which initially refused to go beyond the launch screen. Problems, problems, problems. Anyway yep your solution works, deviceready is firing, thanks again and have a happy new year !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the right version of node installed. Phonegap checks the node version during installation but if you switch to an other (older) version later on, it just silently fails at compile time which somehow causes the deviceready event not to fire.